# SharePoint list lookup for supplier and other information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, custom-form, cascading

I am used to infopath form where you can  fill in drop down of a field with suppliers name. Upon selecting the suppliers name i can use filters to populate other fields such as suppliers contact , address etc.

It was an easy process.

How can i do the same in the default SharePoint forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can edit the Default SharePoint form via Library-> Form Web parts-> Default Edit Form, and add a Content Editor web part into it, then add jQuery code into the content editor web part to achieve it.

Reference:
[Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.sg/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html)
[Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)
[Two Level Cascading Drop Down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)